# Как с помощью flask_sqlalchemy реализовать логическое ИЛИ?

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Возник такой вопрос: Во flask приложении нужно реализовать запрос к БД примерно следующего вида: `SELECT ALL FROM table WHERE firstUserID LIKE X OR secondUserID LIKE X`. Дело в том, что во flask версии sqlalchemy нет функции `or_` (или я не знаю как ее импортировать/вызывать). Данная функция есть в полноценной версии sqlalchemy, однако с ней приложение не заводится, а через flask_sqlalchemy можно реализовать только логический AND. Если кто то сталкивался с подобным вопросом и смог его решить, прошу совета. Не очень хочется делать два запроса к БД вместо одного.

Запросы создаю примерно следующим образом:

```
User.query.filter(User.login == login).all()
```

где login - переменная строчного типа, а User - класс, наследующийся от `SQLAlchemy.Model` и задающий таблицу в БД.

Comment: Что мешает использовать or_ из sqlalchemy вместе с flask_sqlalchemy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вместо функции `or_` из sqlalchemy можете использовать оператор `|`:

```py
User.query.filter((User.email == email) | (User.login == login)).all()
```

Пример:

```py
# app.py
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'url_or_path/to/database'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(30))


class UserQuery(object):
    @staticmethod
    def get_user_id_by_email_or_name(email=None, name=None):
        user = User.query.filter((User.email == email) | (User.name == name)).first()
        return user.id if hasattr(user, 'id') else None
```

Refs:

[Using OR in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942547/using-or-in-sqlalchemy)

[Flask SQLAlchemy filter by value OR another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535547/flask-sqlalchemy-filter-by-value-or-another)

[Column Elements and Expressions](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html)

Comment: `'\'name\' cannot be None'` -> `"'name' cannot be None"` :) Да и не понятно зачем нужен конструктор с дефолтными полями, если они должны быть заполнены. Да и разве нужен тут конструктор, он ведь и так будет создан по полям класса

Comment: код для примера взял отсюда https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40535547/flask-sqlalchemy-filter-by-value-or-another только для того, чтобы показать, как оно работает :d
upd: убрал конструктор